# Adding blank lines in between

Tags: c#, csv, file-writing

I have a function that exports a data table to a csv file. And there is a blank line added after every other line.

## This is the output to a txt file

```
Assets|Profit Center|Plant|Asset Class|Depr Account|Cost Center|Inventory Number|Location|Cap Date|Last Inventoried|Deactivation Date|Asset Description|Acquis Value|Monthly Depriciation|O dep posted|Accum Dep|Book Value|Serial|Inventory Note|Inventory Comments|LFAC|Room|Supplier Name|Manufacturer of Asset|EFO|Asset Main Text|EGM|Person Responsible|TOP Sider|Type Name & Eccn Number|Std|Class|Inventory Status|Inventoried By|Prior Room|Comments

1007309|DAHQ|DAHQ|32752|3375|DAHQB00760|QJQX0290E1|P229|3/25/1990|4/30/2013|0|CTC, West Wing Land Improvements|0| - |0| -   | -   |0|0|-|Thompson Jennifer|CTC|CTCWBLDG|X / X|0 / 0 / X / Huntzinger,Joe|LAND IMPROVEMENTS|-|-|-|0|3275|Land Improvements|NOT FOUND|||

1007313|DAHQ|DAHQ|32752|3375|DAHQB00760|QJQX0890E1|P229|9/25/1990|4/30/2013|0|CTC, West Wing Land Improvements|0| - |0| -   | -   |0|0|-|Thompson Jennifer|CTC|CTCWBLDG|X / X|0 / 0 / X / Huntzinger,Joe|LAND IMPROVEMENTS|-|-|-|0|3275|Land Improvements|NOT FOUND|||
```

## Here is the code

```
try
{
  data.Tables[tableMaster].Columns.Remove("ID");
}
catch
{
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = data.Tables[tableMaster].Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[tableMaster].Rows)
{
  IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
  sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", sb.ToString());
```

How can I avoid the blank lines?

Comment: What are you using to get this data, Open XML?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth I am filling this data from a csv originally then my program updates some columns. After that i would like to just export it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution use a string list instead of string builder:

```
List<String> strlst = new List<String>();
strlst.Add(String.Join("|", data.Tables[tableMaster].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName)));

foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[tableMaster].Rows)
{
  IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
  strlst.Add(string.Join("|", fields));
}
File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", strlst);
```

Comment: When i convert the test.txt back to a .csv it still puts a empty line inbetween each line of data.

Comment: How do you convert?